# get particular string using java

Tags: java

I have a string like this:

```
URL#appURL=xre://ovaplatform.net:143/frace?accountId={APP:accountId}&config.base64=eyJlbmFibGVIYXhlZSI6InRydWUiLCJhcHBOYW1lIjoiR2VuZXJpY0NoYXJpb3RBcHAiLCJzaG93VG9hc3RlciI6InRydWUiLCJ1cmwiOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnlhaG9vLmNvbSJ9&samlAssertion={ATTR:token}&timeZone={APP:timeZone}&sessionId={APP:sessionId}&deviceId={APP:deviceId}&config.type=base64"
```

From this string i have to get the value of config.base64

```
eyJlbmFibGVIYXhlZSI6InRydWUiLCJhcHBOYW1lIjoiR2VuZXJpY0NoYXJpb3RBcHAiLCJzaG93VG9hc3RlciI6InRydWUiLCJ1cmwiOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnlhaG9vLmNvb
```

Is there any easy to way to get that using java?

Comment: make use of java.util.regex

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If order of the parameters are going to be same, then we can do -

```
String url = "your_URL_goes here";
String startKey = "&config.base64=";
String endKey = "&samlAssertion=";

String result = url.substring(url.indexOf(startKey) + startKey.length(), url.indexOf(endKey));
```

In case you want `&` as end key, you can try:

```
String startKey = "&config.base64=";
String endKey = "&";

String tmpStr = url.substring(url.indexOf(startKey) + startKey.length());
String result = (tmpStr.indexOf(endKey) == -1) ? tmpStr : tmpStr.substring(0, tmpStr.indexOf(endKey));
```

Please remember, if `&` is part of your parameter value, this might not work. So, be careful.

Comment: your code sounds nice .but endkey may varies.so can i use '&' only in place of endkey.but am getting array index error

Answer (score 1):

Use regex when the string starts to meet a given critiera, alternatively use String's `.split` on the `config.base64` and take whatever string comes after, then split that against the & or `samlAssertion` and take the first section

```
String[] parts = string.split("config.base64=");
String config = parts[1];
String[] partsConfig = config.split("&samlAssertion=");
String configOnly = partsConfig[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

class KeyValueFromURL
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String url = "URL#appURL=xre://ovaplatform.net:143/frace?accountId={APP:accountId}&config.base64=eyJlbmFibGVIYXhlZSI6InRydWUiLCJhcHBOYW1lIjoiR2VuZXJpY0NoYXJpb3RBcHAiLCJzaG93VG9hc3RlciI6InRydWUiLCJ1cmwiOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnlhaG9vLmNvbSJ9&samlAssertion={ATTR:token}&timeZone={APP:timeZone}&sessionId={APP:sessionId}&deviceId={APP:deviceId}&config.type=base64";
        int start = url.indexOf('?');
        String keyValue = url.substring(start + 1);
        String[] pairs = keyValue.split("&");
        Map<String, String> pair = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (String p : pairs) {
            int eq = p.indexOf('=');
            pair.put(p.substring(0, eq), p.substring(eq + 1));
        }
       // System.out.println(pair.toString());
        System.out.println(pair.get("config.base64"));
    }
}
```

Assuming `&` is used to split the `key value` pair and the `key value` pairs starts after the first `?`. You can use this class to store all the key value pair in a `HashMap` and get the `value` from the `key`